# I have converted float into string but it doesn't return quotes

Tags: python, floating-point

```
x = 1.00006
print(str(x))
Output: 1.00006
Desired Output: '1.00006'
```

I have typed the above code into repl.it and as you can see it returns a float, Why?

Comment: it's a string, don't worry

Comment: You can always check your output type with type(str(x))

Answer (score 2):

It is a string but it just displayed as `1.00006` (without `'` `'`)

**Proof:**

```
x = str(1.00006)
print(type(x))

#gives <class 'str'>
```

**type this in IDLE:**

```
x = 1.00006
```

```
print(str(x))
```

it will give you the `''`

**If you doesn't have an IDLE:**

```
x = str(1.0001)
print(repr(x))
```

You can use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Comment: Don't have IDLE working on a Chromebook. The problem is that when writing programs that use typecasting it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Using `repr`,

```py
>>> x = 1.00006
>>> str_x = str(x)
>>> str_x
'1.00006'
>>> print(str_x)
1.00006
>>> repr(str_x)
"'1.00006'"
>>> print(repr(str_x))
'1.00006'
```